This code for permutation of Strings isn't working
I have a simple java code for permutation of String array using backtrack. It gives the concatenated String array elements as result.
public List<String> permute(String[] words) {
    List<String> ans = new ArrayList<>();
    String sol = "";

    int n = words.length;

    backtrack(ans, sol, n, words);

    return ans;
}

public void backtrack(List<String> ans, String sol, int n, String[] words) {
    if(sol.length() == (n * words[0].length())) {
        ans.add(sol);
        return;
    }

    for(String x: words) {
        if(!sol.contains(x)) {
            sol += x;
            backtrack(ans, sol, n, words);
            sol = sol.substring(0, sol.length() - words[0].length());
        }
    }
}

If I give input as ["bar","foo","the"], it is able to produce all the possible permutations
barfoothe
barthefoo
foobarthe
foothebar
thebarfoo
thefoobar

Similarly, if the input is of length 2 or 3, then it works like a charm but when the input has 4 String elements, let's say ["word","good","best","good"], the output is just [].
This is the actual problem and I wanna know why this doesn't work for length more than 3 and how to fix this issue.

Because !sol.contains(x) which checks if a word is already in. Your array contains the word good twice so it will never add it again. This never satisfies the sol.length() == (n * words[0].length() and thus it will never be added.
